# How to pass command argument while selecting a Menu Item in System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, menu, command

I have a Menu. When user clicks on the menu , I need to pass a command argument. How is that done ?

This is the code for

```
<asp:Menu ID="NoticeManagerMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemClick="NoticeManagerMenu_MenuItemClick">
            <StaticMenuStyle HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle BackColor="#C0C0FF" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#C0C0FF" BorderColor="#C0C0FF" />
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="Silver" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem  Text="List"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Insert"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

In the code behind, I wish to use like this

```
protected void NoticeManagerMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandArgument.Equals("Update"))
        {


        }
        else
        {

        }           
    }
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties seem to be read-only. You might try to compare the `Text` of your menu item.

Comment: Thanks Axarydax..Your suggestion will help me to go ahead...The commandName , commadArgument are empty when an Item is selected..So we need to know how these properties can be set..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Value attribute?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Anuraj..Value attribute will definitly serve the purpose..I wanted to check how the command parameters can be used here